# Is there a way that I can wait for the return of a navigation page and then execute some code after the return?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code:

```
async void openPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   await Navigation.PushAsync(new CFSPage());
   // some code here that gets executed only after CFSPage is closed
}
```

What I would like to do is to only execute the code after the CFS page has returned.

Is there some way that I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using OnDisappearing() in the CFSPage?

You could pass a reference from the pushing page to CFSPage and the react on the disappearing of the pushed page.

```
async void openPage(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   await Navigation.PushAsync(new CFSPage(this));
}
```

On CFSPage:

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();
    this.ActionsOnPushedPageDisappears();
}
```